# Можно ли запустить программу в скрытом режиме?

Tags: windows, winapi

Можно ли запустить программу (Exe файл) в скрытом режиме + чтобы дочерние окна программы тоже скрывались? Если да, с помощью какой программы можно это сделать? Или же на каком языке из стандартных языков (который не нужно будет дополнительно устанавливать в Windows) можно это написать?

**Обновление**

> что вы подразумеваете под "скрытым режимом"?  
> Чтобы программа выполнялась, но окна не было видно.
>
> 2) что вы подразумеваете под "стандартными языками которые не нужно устанавливать в Windows"?

Ну как пример VBS, скрипт уже сразу будет работать в Windows. Но вообще меня интересует и отдельно устанавливаемый софт, или же языки программирования (но желательно те, которые не нужно ставить отдельно в Windows, как я уже и говорил).

Comment: Если приложение не ваше, то можно DLL Injection на С/С++ написать.

Comment: С/C++ для меня очень сложный. Там много писать нужно для этого DLL Injection?

Comment: Увы, но это только с виндовыми прогами, а-ля notepad, regedit и тп работает... Остальным прогам пофиг на данный vbs

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли запустить программу (Exe файл) в скрытом режиме

что вы подразумеваете под "скрытым режимом"?

> чтобы дочерние окна программы тоже скрывались?

можно

> Или же на каком языке из стандартных языков (который не нужно будет дополнительно устанавливать в Windows) можно это написать?

1) практически на любом

2) что вы подразумеваете под "стандартными языками которые не нужно устанавливать в Windows"?

> Если да, с помощью какой программы можно это сделать?

так вас программы или языки интересуют?

Answer (score 0):

[[@Bazinga](/users/24125/bazinga)](/users/24125/bazinga): Если это ваша программа — куча делов, не создавайте окно, и всё.

Если это чужая программа, всё сложнее — если программа захочет показать окно, вам придётся это отлавливать и скрывать показанные окна. Ну и программа имеет законное право не рассчитывать на такое беспардонное противодействие и крешнуться.

Comment: Это не моя программа. Пока что еще ни одного полезного совета :(

Answer (score 0):

Tray minimizer, Anvir Task Mng

Comment: На счет первой программы не ясно, мне не нужно сворачивать в трей.
К чему вторая программа - вообще не понял.

Comment: Видимо, первой убераешь в трей, второй скрываешь её там.

И всё работает, как описано в условии.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, в каких условиях запускается ваша программа, но, как вариант, можно запускать её через *Планировщик заданий* от имени другого пользователя. А через диспетчер задач можно будет отслеживать её запуск и, если что, завершать её выполнение.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял,то(VBS):

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.run "notepad.exe",0
```

-- запускает блокнот, который виден только в диспетчере задач